# ProcessStartInfo.Verbs for .png and .jpg are only "printto"

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I am trying to open or edit files with the ProcessStartInfo class. If I use .docx, .txt or similar it works. Only with .jpg and .png there are problems.

I'm using `var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(someJpgOrPngFile)` and in the `psi.Verbs` is only the *printto* Attribute.

I have tested the following code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40340313) to get the available verbs and there I get *open* and *shelledit*

If I set the verb manually, like *open* or *edit* the file will be opened but this is not an option for me due to my code.

Does anyone have an idea why I get only printto as verb?

I'm using .NetFramework 4.6.1

Comment: you want to edit the jpg , png file? so  why you need printto?

Comment: @ThierryV Read the question again. OP needs the open / edit verb but only get the printto verb and is asking why

Comment: @Hadda the answer to your question is inside the link you gave: *The ProcessStartInfo.Verbs property is somewhat broken as it does not consider the way how newer versions of Windows (Windows 8 and above afaik) retrieve the registered application*

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks I have probably read over. Is there possibly a workaround or a better method to call the standard program

Comment: You know how to get all possible verbs (see your link), you know how to set a verb (see your question) - well, what is your problem? Setting a verb from one of the possibles? Just do it

Comment: The problem is, if I want to call for example an _edit_, this is not indicated with the possible verbs.